# Way to find coefficient in the given expression

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I need to find the number of distinct ways in which **K** unlabeled objects can be distributed in **N** labeled urns allowing at most **10 objects** to fall in each urn i.e
Coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1 + x + x^{2} + x^3 + ....x^{10})^n$ .
How can this be computed?

Comment: I am sorry, but I couldn't get the meaning of this. 
Cna you please explain? What is f(k)?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg you mean perhaps $f^{(k)}(0)/k!$?

Comment: What does f(k) mean? It would be great if one can explain

Comment: Note that $1 + x + \cdots + x^{10} = \frac{1 - x^{11}}{1-x}$. It could be useful.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you! My wife bothers me.

Comment: @Gribouillis how can that expression help?
I need to code it in some form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction on $q$, one has

$${\left({\left(1-x\right)}^{{-n}}\right)}^{\left(q\right)} = \frac{\left(n-1+q\right) !}{\left(n-1\right) !}(1-x)^{-n-q}$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{{\left(1-x\right)}^{n}} = \sum _{q = 0}^{\infty } \binom{n-1+q}{n-1} {x}^{q}$$

One could use the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) to compute

$${\left(1+\cdots +{x}^{10}\right)}^{n} = {\left(1-{x}^{11}\right)}^{n} \frac{1}{{\left(1-x\right)}^{n}} = \left(\sum _{p = 0}^{n} {\left({-1}\right)}^{p} \binom{n}{p} {x}^{11 p}\right) \left(\sum _{q = 0}^{\infty } \binom{n-1+q}{n-1} {x}^{q}\right) = \sum _{k = 0}^{\infty } {a}_{k} {x}^{k}$$

which seems to give

$$\boxed{{a}_{k} = \sum _{p = 0}^{\min  \left(n , \frac{k}{11}\right)} {\left({-1}\right)}^{p} \binom{n}{p} \binom{n-1+k-11 p}{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can take $\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$, where
$$f(x)=(1+x+...+x^{10})^n.$$
$f^{(k)}(0)$ it's the $k-th$ derivative of $f$ for $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Is there a way I can code it? I mean is there a way this can be converted to a program?

Comment: I think you can do it. You can use recursion  and $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$.

Comment: You can use also the Leibniz's rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule